# Problem with refreshing the website by GULP only once time

Tags: gulp

I would like to ask you for a help. I have a problem with browsersync. I want to learn this tool, and working with tutorial on the WEB, i typed a code but it works only once. Namely, while i put any changes in HTML file, it browser doesn't reload. It realoads only once and never more.

Below is my code. TIA

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('reload', function(){
   browserSync.reload();

});

gulp.task('serve', function(){

    browserSync({
        server: 'src'
    });

    gulp.watch('src/*.html', gulp.series('reload'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('reload', function(done){
   browserSync.reload();
   done();
});


gulp.task('serve', function(done){

  browserSync({
    server: 'src'
  });

  gulp.watch('src/*.html', gulp.series('reload'));
  done();
});
```

You can see in the above code I have added `done()` callbacks - you need those to signal async completion so that the tasks can be fired a second, etc. time.